# Helm condition check on two values and return useful message

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to check the following values and would like to give the user of the chart a useful message during rendering/installing. My condition is already working but its not exiting its just does not render if condition is failing.

```yaml
clusterabc:
  - name: dc1
    replica: 2
    ip: ["xx", "y"]
# my condition is to check the length of ip array and the replica should be same if not then use should get a message to check... this mismatch
```

This is working but it throws not a error
`{{- if and (eq (len $value.ip | int) ($value.replica | int))) (eq $.Values.dc $value.name  }}`

How can I give the user a error like the `required` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fail](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#fail)

Unconditionally returns an empty string and an error with the specified text. This is useful in scenarios where other conditionals have determined that template rendering should fail.

fail "Please accept the end user license agreement"

---

demo

values.yaml

```yaml
clusterabc:
  - name: dc1
    replica: 3
    ip: ["xx", "y"]
```

template/NOTES.txt

```yaml
Check the length of ip array and the replica should be same
{{- $flag := true -}}
{{- range $i, $val := $.Values.clusterabc -}}
{{- if ne (len $val.ip | int) ($val.replica | int) -}}
{{- $flag = false }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- if not $flag -}}
{{ fail "check clusterabc fail..." }}
{{- else }}
check clusterabc success...
{{- end -}}
```

helm install xxxx .

output:

```yaml
Error: execution error at (xxx/templates/NOTES.txt:xx:x): check clusterabc fail...
```

Comment: cool thx for the help, work perfectly and the reference to the docs. Feels bit odd to do checks in the NOTES.txt I thought till to put informations for the user of a helm chart into NOTES.txt and not conditions and checks